# Rails - Inline CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, erb

So I'm making a user profile page for my app. However I want the user's avatar to have an inset white box-shadow. Therefore using `<img />` isn't an option since it doesn't support inset shadows (or at least not in Chrome). So instead I'm using a `<div>` with some inline css to set the image. Here's kinda what I want but of course it wont work.

`<div id="avatar" style="background: <%= @person.avatar %>"></div>`

Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `avatar` the actual URL of the image? In that case:

```
<div id="avatar" style="background-image: url('<%= current_person.avatar %>')"></div>
```

Make sure that the `width` and `height` match the image dimensions in the CSS.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was just missing the = in <%= ... %>

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work pretty well

```
<div id="avatar" style="background:url(<%= current_person.avatar %>) no-repeat;" width="<%= User.AVATAR_WIDTH %>" height="<%= User.AVATAR_HEIGHT %>"></div>
```

`User.AVATAR_WIDTH` and `User.AVATAR_HEIGHT` should be defined in your `app/models/user.rb` as something like:

```
class User
  AVATAR_WIDTH = 250
  AVATAR_HEIGHT = 250
end
```